# Codeigniter does not keep E-Mail Field Value

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-2

I got a strange error with keeping form values in CodeIgniter when validation fails.
I am using many fields in a form, one of which is the E-Mail.

I have implemented the validation rules for E-Mail as follows:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','E-Mail',
'trim|required|xss_clean|is_unique[user.user_email]|callback_validateEmail');
```

The `validateEmail` function is as follows:

```
 function validateEmail($email){
        $this->load->helper('email');
        if((!valid_email($email))){
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validateEmail',
              'The E-Mail you entered is invalid');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In the form, I am using the following code for the E-Mail field :

```
<td align="left">
   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" 
          value="<?php echo set_value('email');?>">
</td>
```

What happens is, the E-Mail value is preserved when the user enters invalid E-Mail values, like "abc123", or "abc123@" . But when the user enters a correct E-Mail Address, say "abc@yahoo.com", and the form validation fails due to error in some other field, the value of the E-Mail field is not preserved and it vanishes.

I have no clue why this fails. Can someone please throw some light?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: CodeIgniter has a [`valid_email` rule](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference) built in to the Form Validation library by default -- no need for a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function is not returning true for valid emails.

Try returning true when the email is valid.

```
function validateEmail($email){
    $this->load->helper('email');
    if((!valid_email($email))){
    $this->form_validation->set_message('validateEmail','The E-Mail you entered is invalid');
    return false;
    }
return true;
 }
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! It works, but if you could explain what the set_value has to do with returning values, that would be great. Thanks anyway:)